# Regex for serial number matching 2 letters and 7 numbers

Tags: c#, regex, validation, integer

Is there any regex for validating a serial number input, the range should be between **DC0001000** to **DC9999999**.

I searched through the internet but I didn't find any solution for this validating serial number regex.

The Prefix **DC** is mandatory and the next 7 digits must be in the range **(0001000  -  9999999)**.

I tried with this regex -

```
[DC]{1}\d{7}[0001000-9999999]
```

but it didn't work for me.

Is there a regex that will match this?

Comment: why don't you take everything after `DC`, convert it to `int` and check the range

Comment: Thanks ..... i can do that but I am looking for regex ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we're going for the shortest one, how about this?

```
DC(?!0000)\d{7}
```

Comment: Except this one matches. `DC0000999` which is wrong.

Comment: @JürgenSteinblock i don't think it **[matches](https://regex101.com/r/fT5eD4/1)**

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted the regex. Brilliant solution +1

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
^DC(?=\d{0,3}[1-9])\d{7}$
```

It checks that the string starts with `DC` and then a positive look ahead checks that one of the following four digits isn't zero - and then 7 digits.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dR4lW0/5).

**Edit** simplified (removed the unnecessary first test)

Answer (score -1):

you are looking look ahead regular expressions. These expressions wont change reg ex pointer. so that pointer can remain at -1 and you can visit the entire string "n" of times.
?=(expression1)?=(expression2)...?=(expression_n)

Also useful in password policy verification.

Comment: please provide reason for down voting. I will try to correct it!

Answer (score -1):

Hi try this for RegExp beginers

```
([D]{1}[C]{1}[0]{3})?([D]{1}[C]{1}[0]{3}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3})|([D]{1}[C]{1}[1-9]{1})?([D]{1}[C]{1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{6})|([D]{1}[C]{1}[0-9]{1}[1-9]{1})?([D]{1}[C]{1}[0-9]{1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{5})|([D]{1}[C]{1}[0-9]{2}[1]{1})?([D]{1}[C]{1}[0-9]{2}[1]{1}[0-9]{4})
```